# Vim - Copy Nth word of each line, from line 10-100, to end of line

Tags: vim

I have a Java Class

```
public class Constants{
    public static final MyClass field1 = new MyClass("arg1"); // line 10
    public static final MyClass field2 = new MyClass("arg2");
    ...
    public static final MyClass field101 = new MyClass("arg101"); //line 100
}
```

I want the 5th word of each line to be appended as the second argument of `MyClass`'s constructor As:

```
public class Constants{
    public static final MyClass field1 = new MyClass("arg1", "field1"); // line 10
    public static final MyClass field2 = new MyClass("arg2", "field2");
    ...
    public static final MyClass field101 = new MyClass("arg101", "field101"); //line 100
}
```

To simplify, lets not care about the `");`s at the end of each line.
How can I put the fifth word from line 10 to line 100 to the end of each line with a vim command?

Comment: You can use macros for that http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros. Just record it on the first line and execute on all the others.

Comment: I managed to follow your hints, I wonder can I apply macro across line 10-100 without hitting @@ on every line?

Comment: @user2829759: use repeat count: `10@a` replays the macro `a` 10 times.

Comment: Also, FYI this question should be in [vi.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:10,100normal! 0f=byiwf)i, "<C-v><C-r>""<CR>
```

In English:

- from line `10` to line `100`,
- execute the following normal command without caring for remappings,
- go to the first column of the line,
- jump to the first `=`,
- go back one word,
- yank that word,
- jump to the first closing parenthesis,
- enter insert mode before the parenthesis,
- insert `, "`,
- followed by the content of the unnamed register (the word we yanked before),
- followed by `"`.

The whole thing could be done with a recording, of course:

```
qq
0f=byiwf)i, "<C-r>""<Esc>
q
:10,100norm! @q
```

Comment: Note that both my solution and lcd047's require a bit of experience with Vim. Coming up with an abstract macro (without actual editing) may not be as easy/intuitive as actually recording it and coming up with the right substitution pattern can become an exercise in frustration pretty quickly. I would argue that literal macros are a bit more intuitive than regular expressions because they are somewhat closer to spoken language but neither are, of course, universal solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
:10,100s/\v^%(\s*\w+){4}\s+(\w+).*\zs\ze\)/, "\1"/
```

Edit: spelling it out:

- `:10,100` - apply to lines 10 -- 100
- `s/.../.../` - substitute
- `\v` - change regexp syntax to "very magic", so we can write `%(...)`, `{...}`, and `+` instead of `\%(...\)`, `\{...}`, and `\+`
- `^` - anchor at beginning of line
- `%(...)` - non-capturing group; identical to `(...)`, except it doesn't create a backreference (that is, it doesn't add anything to `\1`, `\2`, ..., `\N`)
- `\s*\w+` - spaces + word
- `{4}` - repeat last item 4 times; that is, skip first four words
- `\s+` - skip spaces
- `(\w+)` - capture next word in `\1`
- `.* ... \)` - skip to last parenthesis; `)` becomes `\)` because of `\v`
- `\zs` - start replacing here; match everything, but replace only the part to the right of `\zs`
- `\ze` - end replacing here; match everything, but replace only the part to the left of `\ze`
- `/, "\1"/` - insert `, "foo"`; `\1` comes from `(\w+)`, and since we have `\zs` and `\ze` next to each other, the effect is to replace the empty string at that point with `, "foo"`.

Comment: regex has always been foreign language to me. mind to explain a bit?